# Ionic 3 Type issue on fileEntry.copyTo

Tags: typescript, ionic3

On my Ionic 3 app, I want to copy a file on a new directory got by the cordova plugin file but I get a type issue :

```
Argument of type 'Entry' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DirectoryEntry'. Property  'createReader' is missing in type 'Entry'
```

Any of you knows how to get trough this issue ?

my code :

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uriFichierSource).then(fileEntry =>
{
  if(newName == null)
    newName = fileEntry.nativeURL.split('/').pop();
  else if(newName == "")
    newName = fileEntry.nativeURL.split('/').pop();

  this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(repertoireCiblepath).then(dirEntry => {
    fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry,newName, entry =>{
      resolve(newName);
    }, function(error){
      resolve(newName);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#resolveDirectoryUrl), it looks like the second call to `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` should be replaced with `resolveDirectoryUrl` in order to get a `DirectoryEntry` to pass to `copyTo`.